# Error C++ compiling Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: gcc, c++

```
c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-GR’; did you mean ‘-R’?
c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-EHsc’
c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Zm200’
c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-nologo’
c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std:c++17’; did you mean ‘-std=c++17’?
```

**From Comments:**

```
c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-GR’; did you mean ‘-R’?
c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-EHsc’
c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Zm200’ c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-nologo’
c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std:c++17’; did you mean ‘-std=c++17’?
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/exampleED.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/exampleED.dir/exampleED.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:104: CMakeFiles/exampleED.dir/all] 
Error 2 make: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2 –
```

```
emil@DESKTOP-MTLDFE4:~/projects/session2_solution/build$ cmake . -- Configuring done --
Generating done -- Build files have been written to: /home/emil/projects/session2_solution/build emil@DESKTOP-MTLDFE4:~/projects/session2_solution/build
$ make [ 16%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/exampleED.dir/exampleED.cc.o c++:
error: unrecognized command line option ‘-GR’; did you mean ‘-R’? c++: 
error: unrecognized command line option ‘-EHsc’ c++:
error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Zm200’ c++:
error: unrecognized command line option ‘-nologo’ –
```

Comment: @EmilMemmedzade Your question is lacking some important details. For example:  1. What application are you attempting to compile? 2. What steps have you taken to compile it?  Please place this information as *an edit within your question* and then wait *patiently* for a response...

Comment: It looks like you're trying to pass [MSVC compiler options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options-listed-alphabetically?view=msvc-170) to the GNU `g++` compiler